# How do I add a newsletter?

Tags: support, newsletter

I'd like to add Stack Exchange newsletter from a couple of subsites. At https://stackexchange.com/newsletters I can get a preview of the different newsletters and go to the respective sites. However, I cannot seem to find a button for me to add the different newsletters?

Comment: Have you tried clicking **Subscribe**? As this is network-wide it probably belongs on MetaSE, not MetaSO

Comment: Where? http://imgur.com/FkEzQxu

Comment: Good question! That's not what I see; whether signed in or not there's a link to subscribe above each link to preview.

Comment: Hidden by an ad blocker perhaps? Looks like the Fanboy's Annoyances list hides the Subscribe button. Perhaps others do as well.

Comment: Thanks, disabling the adblocker for stackoverflow.com solved the issue. Feel free to create an answer.

Comment: @felbo if that solved your problem you could at least upvote the answer as well as accept it.  The same curiosities on SO exists on meta sites as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ad blocking lists will hide the **Subscribe** button. For example, the [Fanboy's Annoyances List](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/) contains the following element hiding rule in their list:

```
##.newsletter-subscribe
```

Disabling the ad blocking software for the page should reveal the hidden **Subscribe** buttons.